# Accessing to the static readonly properties as an array

Tags: typescript

There is an example

```
export class BIDS {
  static readonly ADDRESS: IBID = { ID: '849541B3-1C2B-4D68-97B5-BC2212FB5B59', UID: 'address' };
  static readonly ORDER_FORM: IBID = { ID: '73713334-DE9E-43A1-8F7C-D664A9CA37C6', UID: 'orderform' };
  static readonly ORDER_LINE: IBID = { ID: '21A0018B-5BBC-4A18-B439-D5133685F793', UID: 'orderline' };

  static getIDbyUID(uid: string): string {
    return ????
  }
}

export interface IBID {
  ID: string;
  UID: string;
}
```

I am wondering, is it possible to write getIDByUID without creating an array of properties, something like that:

```
static getIDbyUID(uid: string): string {
  return BIDS.<static_properties>.find(e => e.UID == uid).ID;
}
```

I mean how to collect these properties programmatically, without manual enumeration (`[ BIDS.ADDRESS, BIDS.ORDER_FORM ... ]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
export class BIDS {
  static readonly ADDRESS: IBID = { ID: '849541B3-1C2B-4D68-97B5-BC2212FB5B59', UID: 'address' };
  static readonly ORDER_FORM: IBID = { ID: '73713334-DE9E-43A1-8F7C-D664A9CA37C6', UID: 'orderform' };
  static readonly ORDER_LINE: IBID = { ID: '21A0018B-5BBC-4A18-B439-D5133685F793', UID: 'orderline' };

  static getIDbyUID(uid: string): string {
    let props = Object.keys(BIDS);
    let filterDatas = props.map(p => BIDS[p]);
    return (filterDatas.find(e => e.UID == uid) || {}).ID
    }
 }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-stackoverflow-53929153)

> `Object.keys(BIDS);` will return `["getIDbyUID", "ADDRESS", "ORDER_FORM", "ORDER_LINE"]` all BIDS propertes include all methods but it s' ok in that case you will got `undefined`

Comment: `return Object.values(BIDS).find(({ UID }) => UID === uid).ID;` also works. (I didn't realize this syntax provided enumerable properties)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I found `Object.keys(BIDS)` return `["getIDbyUID", "ADDRESS", "ORDER_FORM", "ORDER_LINE"]` also work fine 